# How to keep vuetify date picker in sync with input?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a `v-date-picker` similar to the one in [Vuetify documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/date-pickers/#formatting). I'm using the one that allows you to type dates on the `input`, besides allowing to select a date on the picker (see the anchored link I shared).

The problem is, if you are typing a date on the input while the date picker is open, the date on the picker will not be updated. From the user perspective, it will seem as if the old date is still selected.

Note that I'm already subscribing to the `@input` event on my `input` field, updating the date picker date whenever a valid date is typed. This seems to be a refresh/redraw problem that the picker has, as the calendar will not update to the correct date. It has to be closed and opened again for it to be updated.

The example in Vuetify documentation also has this problem.

Any idea on how can I force the refresh/redraw of the date picker while it is open?

Thanks!

Comment: Some code may help us more here.

Comment: While making a codepen for you @kissu I fixed my own problem, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was creating a CodePen to better show my problem (as @kissu requested) and found that I had a bug on my implementation. That was why the date picker was not being updated with the typed date.

Here is the working template code:

```html
<v-menu
  v-model="menu1"
  :close-on-content-click="false"
  transition="scale-transition"
  offset-y
  max-width="290px"
  min-width="auto"
>
  <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
    <v-text-field
      v-model="formattedDate"
      label="Date"
      prepend-icon="mdi-calendar"
      v-bind="attrs"
      v-on="on"
      @input="dateTyped"
    ></v-text-field>
  </template>
  <v-date-picker v-model="date" no-title @input="datePicked"></v-date-picker>
</v-menu>
<p>Date inside the input field is in <strong>DD/MM/YYYY</strong> format</p>
```

And javascript code:

```js
const App = {
  template: "#app-template",
  data: () => ({
    menu1: false,
    date: "2022-10-25",
    formattedDate: "25/10/2022"
  }),
  methods: {
    datePicked(date) {
      if (!date) return;
      this.formattedDate = this.formatDateForInput(date);
      this.menu1 = false;
    },
    formatDateForInput(date) {
      const [year, month, day] = date.split("-");
      return `${day}/${month}/${year}`;
    },
    dateTyped(date) {
      if (!date || date.length !== 10) return;

      console.log(date);
      this.date = this.formatDateForPicker(date);
    },
    formatDateForPicker(date) {
      const [day, month, year] = date.split("/");
      return `${year}-${month}-${day}`;
    }
  }
};
```

CodePen in case someone wants to check it out in action: https://codepen.io/mcarreira/pen/gOKOepQ